# Cannot render events FullCalendar with JSON

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar ver 3.9.0. I have an issue. The events do not render result of JsonResult in MVC. I checked it by javascript: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');` and it returns no length. But when I use `$.ajax` then it returns two arrays like this: `[{"id":5275,"title":"Test Image","start":"23/08/2018 16:39:47","end":"26/08/2018 16:39:47","backgroundColor":"#17a2b8"},{"id":5276,"title":"Test video","start":"23/08/2018 16:39:47","end":"26/08/2018 16:39:47","backgroundColor":"#17a2b8"}]`

FullCalendar's config:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'basicWeek',
        themeSystem: 'bootstrap4',
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,listWeek'
        },
        events: {
            url: '/Schedule/TrinhChieuSchedule',
            type: 'POST',
            data: model
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            AlertMessageDefaultPosition(err, "warning");
            console.log(err);
        },
    });
```

And this is JsonResult in MVC:

```
public JsonResult TrinhChieuSchedule(ScheduleJsonModel model)
        {
            DateTime? ngayBatDau = null;
            DateTime? ngayKetThuc = null;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ngayBatDau))
                ngayBatDau = DateTime.Parse(model.ngayBatDau);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ngayKetThuc))
                ngayKetThuc = DateTime.Parse(model.ngayKetThuc);

            var list = db.SPC_SP_TrinhChieuSchedule(model.madv, ngayBatDau, ngayKetThuc);

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            var jsonString = serializer.Serialize(list.ToArray());

            return Json(jsonString);
        }
```

Comment: you don't need to serialise the data yourself. MVC will do it for you, and it will do it using JSON.NET instead of JavaScriptSerialiser, which should produce the dates in the correct format. You can just do `return Json(list);` directly, or return Json(list.ToArray());` if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this problem. Just change the date format to FullCalendar standard `"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"`